# How to make Protege 4.3 display chinese character correctly?

Tags: character-encoding, protege

I am using Protege 4.3 to create and organize an Ontology which contains Chinese characters.

[image]

As you can see, some Chinese characters are displayed properly, but others are displayed in little squares. The little squares do not always occur, for example: if I click on the `[]-[]-[]-cheatsheet-[]-[]-[]-[]-[]`, I can the same Chinese characters are displayed without problem.

[image]

Do you know what I can do to make Protege 4.3 display chinese characters correctly and consistently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I could have done further homework for this question. It's a post close to the final solution. (I have to post this as an answer for the length doesn't fit comment box)

To be specific, I found from Protege Mailing List Archive the following feedback post

[p4-feedback] Protege 4.2.0 Chinese Display Problem:

https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/p4-feedback/2012-June/004721.html

> I know this problem and have even fixed it on one occasion. But I don't truly understand it or know what to do about it. I am sorry that I don't have good information on this problem but I will give you my best  current understanding.
>
> In my experience, when this happens the character information is correctly encoded in the OWL file. The problem is exclusively a display problem. This is consistent with your description of the problem - in some of the screens the individuals are displaying correctly.
>
> **I believe that the problem has to do with the configuration of fonts in the java virtual machine.** If you change the instance of java that Protege is using the problem will manifest in different ways or it will go away. When I worked on this problem before (it has happened
>   a  couple of times) I gathered some web pages. Unfortunately [only one of them is still valid](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/intl/fontconfig.html), but perhaps it is part of the solution.

I will post my own investigation results after trying the suggested approach above.

PS: A useful owl example is provided here - [some unicode characters do not display correctly in Protege](https://bmir-gforge.stanford.edu/gf/project/owleditor/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=4138&start=0)